# cannot connect Ubuntu with Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 over Wifi

Tags: android

Cannot connect or see Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 from my Ubuntu machine on Wifi. 
Error message when I scan Wifi from Galaxy Note:   No Windows shares found on network

When connecting Galaxy Note with Ubuntu via USB the sd-card can neither be accessed nor information read!  I have no problem with Windows 7 to connect or save anything in both directions!

Is there a simple solution like an app that will allow to access Ubuntu from Galaxy Note 
or do I have to install additional software on my Ubuntu machine because I read somewhere that Ubuntu cannot read file system of Android devices?

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: If you are rooted you can use [Samba sharing app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You could install a Samba Server, so you can use windows shares(Samba utilizes Windows share folders in Linux) either on your Galaxy Note or your Ubuntu machine.

You could use different apps for this: For example: Airdroid, Bittorrent Sync, etc. many solutions. Just search for it.